# How to find all fields having classes that implement specified interface in intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to find all fields with the `Disposable` interface, so I can know if whether I forgot to call the `dispose()` method on any of them in the cleanup phase.

Is there a way to do that in intelliJ?

I've only managed to find those, whose `dispose()` methods I've already remembered to call. I've done that by ticking the "Usages of methods" checkbox in the find usages options dialog (when doing a search on the `Disposable` interface)... but this wasn't what I need.

Comment: you can build the project and if the method of any implemantation is forgotten it will throw an error.

Comment: Unfortunately the classes I use are not mine. I'm using the libGdx library and I'd prefer not to extend or modify all the disposable classes I'm using from the library.

Comment: If possible, try to replace `Disposable` by (`Auto`)`Closeable`. This allows try-with-resources and most IDEs will also warn on some unsafe usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Edit | Find | Search Structurally. You can copy a predefined template named "fields of class" that can be modified to your needs by removing Init part and specifying a hierarchy constraint for $FieldType$ variable.

You can read more about that functionality at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html

Comment: This did work! I was pretty sure by this time that what I was looking for is simply not possible. I was wrong. This structural search thing looks really useful. Probably will help me a lot in the future too.

Comment: @AdamToth would you mind sharing how you defined the specific constraint?

Comment: [I think I've found out how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53759638/2936460).

Answer (score 0):

```
**Alt+F7**
```

Instead of the `dispose` method, find usages of the interface

`Usages` - if this check box is selected, the search is performed for all references of the class by its name.

This way you will get all the places where `Disposable` interface is being referenced in your workspace

Comment: No, I'm trying to find all **fields** having those classes.

Comment: The problem is if I forgot to call the single method of that interface, it's not being referenced and don't come up in the search results. Btw. I forgot to mention, but I've already did the "Find usages" on the interface itself.

Comment: Then you need to go to each reference of the interface and check manually whether the dispose method is invoked or not. What you are looking for is an AND operation between usage of Interface AND !(usage of dispose method) which I don't think is possible by any shortcut

Comment: Not really, because it seems that if no method is called from the interface it doesn't count as usage even if the field having that interface (or more precisely having a class implementing that interface). But I guess you are right about that it isn't possible. I wouldn't mind the search not having the  !(usage of dispose method) part.

Answer (score -1):

You can find usage of the your interface.
The keycode for that in my system is alt+f7, but it can be different on your system.
So you can right click and `find usage` of your interface.
and then filter it down to
`Usage in extends/implements clause`