# When using a reference in a structural search, how do I filter its fields?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I've [found how to search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35983800/2936460) for all fields and variables of a type that implements a given interface, in my case [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

My current way to do this is first creating a filter for classes that implement AutoCloseable. This filter is derived from the pre-defined filter "implementors of interface (within hierarchy)" by adding a filter on the Interface.

`class $Class$ implements $Interface$ {}` where `$Interface$` is filtered with `text=AutoCloseable`.

After saving that filter as "AutoCloseableFilter", I use another filter that uses it:

`$FieldType$` where `$FieldType$` is filtered with `reference=AutoCloseableFilter`.

That works, but I'd like to be able to skip the step of saving a specific instance of that pre-defined filter, instead setting its filter when using it as a reference.

In other words, I'd like to create a filter where `$FieldType` is filtered by `reference=implementors of interface (within hierarchy)` and then filtering `$Interface$` to a specific interface in one go.

Is that possible in structural search?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case it appears to be enough to specify a text filter on `$FieldType$` instead of a reference filter. Use text `AutoCloseable` and check the `Within type hierarchy` checkbox.

[image: structural search dialog example]